# XSD Possible recursion detected

Tags: xml, recursion, xsd

Good evening, I am trying to build a schema for some XML that I need to validate, however when I use a validation tool, I receive the following error:

> Error!!! Possible recursion detected (element 'box'). Please correct
>   your schema and try again.

Here is the XML I wish to be able to handle with the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<document xmlns="http://somewhere.com"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://somewhere.com/xml/onxy/onyx.xsd"
     version="0.1">

    <surface title="Test Surface">
        <meta name="Author" content="Somebody" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css" />
        <layout>

            <box id="box1">
                <text>Hello World</text>
                <box>
                    <text>How Are You</text>
                    <text>Today</text>
                </box>
            </box>

        </layout>
    </surface>
</document>
```

And here is the XML Schema that is causing the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://somewhere.com"
    xmlns:onyx="http://somewhere.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <!-- A container for multiple sufrace elements. -->
    <xs:element name="document">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="surface" type="onyx:SurfaceType" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="SurfaceType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="meta" type="onyx:MetaType" />
            <xs:element name="link" type="onyx:LinkType" />
            <xs:element name="layout" type="onyx:LayoutType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="LayoutType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="box" type="onyx:ContentType"  />
            <xs:element name="text" type="onyx:ContentType" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:anyAttribute/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ContentType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="box" type="onyx:ContentType"  />
            <xs:element name="text" type="onyx:ContentType" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:anyAttribute/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="MetaType">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="content" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="LinkType">
        <xs:attribute name="rel" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Just to clarify this means I wish to restrict children of `box` and `text` elements to the names `box` and `text` but not restrict how many can occur nor how deep the recursion can go.

I wouldn't have asked if not have searched online and SO thoroughly, thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Your current schema requires every `onyx:box` element to contain another `onyx:box` element, so the inner box in your example is invalid (as is every other finite XML document).

As with any recursion, you need to provide a non-recursive base step as well a recursive step; in content model terms, any element which nests within itself must be allowed not to contain itself.  Your validator appears to be smart enough to notice and to try to help.

(Your ContentType also doesn't allow two `text` elements, so it fails to describe your example in that way, too, but I assume you can clear that up.)

Comment: Just to expand on this answer: the error message is a bit misleading because it suggests that a schema cannot be recursive, which of course isn't the case. The problem here is that it's a non-terminating recursion. In fact there's no rule in the spec against such a schema, but since the schema can never have any valid (finite) instances, it's reasonable of the processor to tell you about this.

Comment: What I am trying to get the schema to recognise is that a box or a text element can only contain box or text elements. Is there no way to express that in xsd?

Comment: Yes, of course there is, but I am not going to write it out for you; my goal is to help you discover it on your own.  Your current schema is a first step, but it appears not to say what you want to say, given that your sample input is not valid against it. Read the answer and MK's comment and think harder. Then look up minOccurs and think about how that might help you define a type against which all the occurrences of onyx:box in your instance would be valid.